# как лучше реализовать функции бибилиотеки

Tags: android, kotlin

Функции выполняют долгие операции (поход в сеть, вычисления)

Рассматриваю два варианта:

1. Делать с коллбэками, внутри, Sdk сам рулить потоками и возвращает в UI поток (**varialOne**)
2. Метод Sdk выполняется в потоке из которого вызвал потребитель (**varianTwo**)

Какой вариант и почему лучше использовать?
p.s. в SDK все завязано на RXJava и SDK по сути только для Android

Вот примерно (Sdk отдельный подключаемый в Gradle проект, Consumer отдельный проект который использует Sdk)

```
class Sdk() {
    private val mainThreadScheduler: Scheduler = if (isAndroid) AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() else anotherUiThread
   
    fun loadData(callback: Callback) {
        loadDataFromNetwork() //библиотека сама обрабатывает переключения по потокам\
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(mainThreadScheduler)
            .doOnSubscribe { callback.onLoading() }
            .subscribe({
                callback.onSuccess(it)
            }, {
                callback.onError(it)
            })
    }

    fun loadData(): Data {
        //библиотека выполняет код в UI (потрибитель должен позоботиться о выпереключении потока)
        return loadDataFromNetwork().blockingGet()
    }
}


class AndroidConsumer {
    val sdk = Sdk()

    fun variantOne() {
        sdk.loadData(object : Callback {
            override fun onLoading() {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onSuccess(value: Data) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
    }

    fun variantTwo() {
        //если у пользователя бибилиотеки RX
        Single.fromCallable { sdk.loadData() }
            .subscribe({ data ->

            }, { error ->

            })


        //если просто Thread, Executors, AsyncTask и т.д.
        Thread {
            val data = sdk.loadData()
            //handle data
        }.start()

        //корутины
        //можно будет заюзать этот метод?
    }
}

//какой-то репозиторий c Rx
fun loadDataFromNetwork(): Single<Data> = Single.just(Data(""))


interface Callback {
    fun onLoading()
    fun onError(e: Throwable)
    fun onSuccess(value: Data)
}

data class Data(val a: String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой способ подходит.

Предлагаю вам самый простой использовать - пусть библиотека выдаёт наружу метод, возвращающий данные, а пользователь библиотеки пусть сам решает как ему этот метод использовать - с RxJava, Coroutines, Thread, <s>AsyncTask</s>.

Если же хочется заморочиться - можете сделать доступными все способы - и с колбэком, и с возвращением `Single` и даже `suspend`.

Comment: Я за вариант varianTwo, но вынужден делать variantOne. В первом варианте, я пока не понимаю, как отменять подписку(наверное пользователи будут заводить bool ключи)..